# LastInsertId with Parse Database

Tags: php, parse-platform

I'm new in Parse and I come from mysql. In mysql, it's possible to get the last id inserted in the database width $db->lastInsertId(). I don't find how to do it with Parse db, can you help me please ?

How to get the last insert id in a Parse Database ?

Thank you

Comment: Have you started with the Parse PHP SDK yet? Did you read the documentation?

Answer (score 1):

With the [Parse PHP SDK](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-php-sdk), everything is Object-based. This means when you create and save the Parse object in your Parse storage, you can use the [`getObjectId()` method of the `ParseObject` to retrieve the object ID after saving](https://www.parse.com/docs/php_guide#objects-saving_anchor):

```
$gameScore = new ParseObject("GameScore");

$gameScore->set("score", 1337);
$gameScore->set("playerName", "Sean Plott");
$gameScore->set("cheatMode", false);

try {
  $gameScore->save();
  echo 'New object created with objectId: ' . $gameScore->getObjectId();
} catch (ParseException $ex) {  
  // Execute any logic that should take place if the save fails.
  // error is a ParseException object with an error code and message.
  echo 'Failed to create new object, with error message: ' + $ex->getMessage();
}
```

From the above example, the notable method we've used is `$gameScore->getObjectId()`. The respective output would be:

> New object created with objectId: xWMyZ4YEGZ

This is different from the `lastInsertId()` method because the value obtained from `getObjectId()` will always be the same for a particular object after it has been saved to the Parse cloud.